# how to restrict video upload for only 6 seconds video in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, video, mp4, jquery-file-upload

I need to restrict videos above 6 seconds while uploading using codeIgniter.

How can I restrict? Is their any script in jQuery or javascript to restrict upload above 6 seconds

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

**I have not tried this answer, but this could solve your problem / or show the direction to attempt.**

add a video element in your DOM
`<video id="video_player"></video>`

then add the event listener

```
    var myVideoPlayer = document.getElementById('video_player');
    myVideoPlayer.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
        console.log(videoPlayer.duration);
    });
```

When a file is selected via the `input` element:

1. 'change' event is fired
2. Get the first [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/File) object from the `input.files` [FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/FileList)
3. Make an [object URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Document_Object_Model_%28DOM%29/window.URL.createObjectURL) that points to the File object
4. Set the object URL to the `video.src` property
5. Video's metadata will be loaded and it will fire `loadedmetadata` event, which will print your duration video's !